# Newtonian gravity for cylindrical geometry

Tags: newtonian-gravity

What is Newtonian gravity for and thus gravitational potential for cylindrical geometry? For spherical geometry the gravitational potential is Gm/r^2. But what is it for cylindrical geometry?

Comment: The gravitational potential is $GMm/r$ not $r^2$ and why do you think it would be any different? $r = | \mathbf{r}|$ is the magnitude of the distance between two bodies. So just make the appropriate coordinate transformations.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Do you mean the gravity generated by a cylindrically shaped mass?

Comment: In the case of compressible flow, due to the gravitational field the source term added in the momentum equation (which is gravitational potential) is Gm/r in the case of cylindrical geometry and Gm/r^2 in the case of spherical geometry. So my question is how does it comes?

Comment: I mean the gravitational force for the cylinder in which mass is distributed and also the cylinder is axisymmetric.

Answer (score 0):

Of course we live in a three dimensional space (forget about time for this example).  We have a large gravitating body and a smaller body under the gravitational influence of the larger.  The small body is so much smaller than the larger that we can safely neglect the gravitational influence it has on the larger body.  Now we will say that the smaller body is at a distance r from the larger body.  Since the space is three dimensional it does not matter where the smaller body is as long as the distance r is maintained.  In other words, all radii will emanate from the center of mass of the large body and extend to the center of mass of the small body.  It does not matter if the gravitating body is a sphere, a cylinder, a square, or any other irregular shape.  We will always see a line connecting the two center of mass points together even if we turn the gravitating body in any direction.

Now lets drop out one dimension and consider a cylindrical body in a space of two dimensions.  When we look at the end of the cylinder we will see a circle with a center of mass in the center and a radial line of length r extending out to the small body no matter where it is (in degrees).  But looking at the side of the cylinder we will see that what was a mass point is now a center of mass line the same length as the cylinder.  What were radial lines in the end view are now seen as any number of perpendicular lines extending from the mass line to the small body  depending on the alignment of the small body with the wall of the cylinder.

Dropping out another dimension will just leave us with a flat plane and all radial lines will be gone (in the sense that they are radial).  We will just see a rectangle with a mass line running down the center and a perpendicular line of length r from the mass line to the small body and a gravitational gradient between the two.

Of course the second and third examples never arise due to natures least action principle which tends to compact all mass density into a sphere surrounding a center point of mass. I don't know how you would calculate the gradient between a mass point and a mass line.  Maybe you could slice the cylinder up into wafer thin slices but you still need the entire mass of the cylinder so you are right back to the three dimensional model even if the cylinder hasn't yet been compacted into a sphere.