# $Gm/r$ in momentum equation of compressible flow for cylindrical geometry

Tags: fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity, flow

In the case of compressible flow, due to the gravitational field, the source term added in the momentum equation (which is gravitational potential) is $Gm/r$ in the case of cylindrical geometry and $Gm/r^2$ in the case of spherical geometry. So my question is how does it come in the case of cylindrical geometry? What would be Poisson's equation for cylindrical geometry?

Comment: You have a spherical attractive object inside a cylinder?

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/489865/2451

Comment: No. The fluid flow is taking inside a cylinder which is axisymmetric.